# How do I use sklearn.metrics to compute micro/macro measures for multilabel classification task?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I have results produced by a multilabel classifier for which I want to compute micro- and macro-precision, recall and F1 scores using `sklearn.metrics` in python, but can't quite figure out how.

I have two binary sparse matrices, `dataOUT` and `dataGT` that represent, respectively, classification results and ground truth for the same dataset. Both matrices are of size `nLabels X nSamples`. Each sample can be labelled with one or more labels, so `dataOUT[i,j]` is `1` if the classifier labeled `j`th sample with `i`th label, and `0` otherwise.

For any given class `i`, I can easily calculate regular precision, recall and F-score by extracting `i`th rows from `dataOUT` and `dataGT` can feeding those to `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support`, e.g. something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support

iLabel = 5 # some specific label

yOUT = np.asarray(dataOUT[iLabel,:].todense()).reshape(-1)
yGT = np.asarray(dataGT[iLabel,:].todense()).reshape(-1)

ps,rs,fs,ss = precision_recall_fscore_support(yGT,yOUT)
p = ps[1]   # Precision for iLabel
r = rs[1]   # Recall for iLabel
f1 = fs[1]  # F1 for iLabel
```

But how do I calculate micro- and macro-measures for the entire dataset, i.e. how do I get a single micro-(P,R,F) and a single macro-(P,R,F) triples for the `(dataOUT,dataGT)` pair rather than for each label separately?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of metrics in scikit-learn support multilabel arguments.
[sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support)
If documentation says:

> 1d array-like, or **label indicator array / sparse matrix**

you can just feed metric with whole y matrix and ground true matrix. But these matrices must have shape [n_samples, n_labels], in other words every row of that matrix must correspond to a set of labels for same sample, and every column - to some label. So you should transpose your matrices.

```
ps,rs,fs,ss = precision_recall_fscore_support(dataGT.T, dataOUT.T)
```

Also read this [Multiclass and multilabel classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification)